# Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root"

Tags: reboot, memory-usage

I have both HHD 1TB and SSD 240GB. I installed ubuntu on my SSD but recently I got this notification `Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root"`

Here is the result of `df -h`. I'm never got this problem before so I'm not sure what is expected from this command.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           786M  2,3M  784M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        19G   17G  541M  97% /
tmpfs           3,9G  143M  3,7G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      217M  217M     0 100% /snap/code/77
/dev/loop3      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11993
/dev/loop2      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11798
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop1      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop6       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1081
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop7       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1169
/dev/loop8      217M  217M     0 100% /snap/code/78
/dev/loop10     6,3M  6,3M     0 100% /snap/curl/371
/dev/loop9      6,3M  6,3M     0 100% /snap/curl/412
/dev/loop11      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop12     165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop14      27M   27M     0 100% /snap/heroku/4076
/dev/loop15     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop13     128M  128M     0 100% /snap/slack/46
/dev/loop17      63M   63M     0 100% /snap/notion-snap/6
/dev/loop16      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/433
/dev/loop18      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop19      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/13270
/dev/loop20      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop21     127M  127M     0 100% /snap/slack/44
/dev/loop22     241M  241M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
/dev/loop23      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/13640
/dev/loop24     169M  169M     0 100% /snap/postman/148
/dev/sdb3        94M  5,2M   89M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb4       186G  8,8G  168G   5% /home
tmpfs           786M   20K  786M   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           786M   40K  786M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I've been deleting some snaps by this command `sudo du -h /var/lib/snapd/snaps` in order to reboot into ubuntu. It even cannot reboot before that which I think might be of the memory problem.

Thanks in advance for your helps

Comment: So what is the question? Your `/` partition is almost full. It is 19 GB. So either increase the size of that partition, or remove something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering why my root partition run out so fast. I was because I selected `/home` folder to push my personal data.

Comment: Your `/home` folder is on another partition. It is only 5% occupied.

Comment: I think it the same partition because when I check for usage of `/` folder. I got this result
`8,9G /var 8,8G /home
`

Comment: You think, but I see `/dev/sdb4       186G  8,8G  168G   5% /home`

Comment: It was initially a bad idea to separate `/` and `/home` on different partitions.

Comment: I had followed a tutorial on the internet and set up 3 partitions which are root, swap, and home. I think it is still OK. Just I'm not aware of that and use it incorrectly.

Comment: These "tutorials on the internet" is a problem;-)

Comment: Haha. Really appreciate your help. At least I got the problem, solve it, and got a lesson :D

Comment: Posted minimum system requirements for Ubuntu Desktop is 25GB.  It would be wise to go bigger.  You do not need a swap partition and if you are miserly on space, it's probably not wise to have a separate home partition either. I would reinstall Ubuntu and use a single partition. The problem with using "tutorials on the internet" is that lots of information can be outdated, lots of people have opinions, and many people have bad opinions and engage in bad practices. There is an official tutorial to [install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview)

Comment: Lots of people still use separate home partitions. It's definitely not required. Many people do it so they can format the root partition or reinstall the OS or install a different OS without having to wipe the home partition.  That's the only benefit. But it's really not even that simple since a lot of applications store user preferences under the users' home folder and these configs might cause problems with different OS versions, flavors, or distros. Do not use partitions soley for organization- that's what folders are for.